# Stop after click and press tab key my frame moving with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I face some jQuery Problem

I want stop moving frame  after click anywhere of body and press tab key.

I have two div and i click anywhere of body of first div and press tab key the my second div appear.

Please help how to stop.

see screen for understating.

http://screencast.com/t/TsBnq0b2ms

Comment: Give us your code, a JSFiddle link will be a great help for us

Comment: For someone with 5K+ rep you should know that this is a poorly asked question. Post your code *in* your question showing us what you've tried please.

Answer (score 0):

provide the code please.

but in general you can use the following:

```
    $( "p" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  // Do something
});
```

all you need to do is figure out where you are clicking to stop.